# Will I lose a privilege when start bounty?

Tags: support, reputation, privileges

I reach some privilege, say at 1500 rep. But now I have a question for which I want to start bounty, but I afraid I will lose my privilege.

Will I lose a privilege when start bounty?

Comment: Yes. Any loss of rep can cause you to lose a privilege.

Comment: @Stijn: But this will limit me to starting bounties

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question. If you drop below 75 rep after starting your bounty, then you will no longer be able to start a new bounty until you reach 75 rep again.

Comment: @Stijn: I can lose my rep by doing bad things: post bad answers, downvote, but also by doing good things: award good answers. I do not expect to lose privilege by doing good things. (check should be: has_privilege if access_level <= given_bounties + curr_rep )

Comment: Well, that's how it works. If you want to change that, post a question with the [meta-tag:feature-request] tag.